# awk to extract and print first occurrence of patterns

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to extract and print the first ocurrence of `NM_` and the portion after the`NP_` starting with `p.`. A `:` is printed instead of the "|" for each. The input file is `tab-delimeted`, but the output does not need to be. The below does execute but prints all the lines in the file not just the patterns. There maybe multiple `NM` or `NP` in my actual data of over 5000 lines, however only the first occurence of each is extracted and printed. I am still a little unclear on the `RSTART` and `RLENGHTH` concepts but, using line 1 as an example from the input:

The `NM` variable would be `NM_020469.2`

The `NP` variable would be `:p.Gly268Arg`

I have included comments as well. Thank you :).

input

```
Input Variant   HGVS description(s) Errors and warnings
rs41302905  NC_000009.11:g.136131316C>T|NM_020469.2:c.802G>A|NP_065202.2:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745   NC_000009.11:g.136131347G>A|NM_020469.2:c.771C>T|NP_065202.2:p.Pro257=
```

desired output

```
rs41302905 NM_020469.2:c.802G>A:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745 NM_020469.2:c.771C>T:p.Pro257=
```

awk

```
awk -F'[\t|]' 'NR>1{ # define FS as tab and `|` to split each, and skip header line
              r=$1; nm=np="";  # create variable r with $1 and 2 variables (one for nm and the other for np, setting them to null)
              for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { # start a loop from line2 and itterate
                  if ($i~/^NM_/) nm=$i;  # extract first NM_ in line and read into i
                  else if ($i~/^NP_/) np=substr($i,index($i,":")); # extract NP_ and print portion after : (including :)
                  if (nm && np) { print r,nm np; break }  # print desired output
              }
          }' input
```

Comment: still talking about "patterns" huh? Sigh.... Also if `There maybe multiple NM or NP in my actual data` then show at least 2 in your sample data otherwise you're inviting solutions to the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -F'[\t|]' 'NR>1{
                  r=$1; nm=np="";
                  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
                      if ($i~/^NM_/) nm=$i;
                      else if ($i~/^NP_/) np=substr($i,index($i,":"));
                      if (nm && np) { print r,nm np; break } 
                  }
              }' input
```

---

- `'NR>1` - start processing from the 2nd record
- `r=$1; nm=np=""` - initialization of the needed variables
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through the fields (starting from the 2nd)
- `if ($i~/^NM_/) nm=$i` - capturing `NM_...` item into variale `nm`
- `else if ($i~/^NP_/) np=substr($i,index($i,":"))` - capturing `NP_...` item into variale `np` (starting from `:` till the end)
- `if (nm && np) { print r,nm np; break }` - if both items has been captured - print them and break the loop to avoid further processing

---

The output:

```
rs41302905 NM_020469.2:c.802G>A:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745 NM_020469.2:c.771C>T:p.Pro257=
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much :). I think I understand but in the edit in my post are my comments correct/close?  Thank you again.

Comment: @Chris, you're welcome, you also have my **bonus** gawk solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525760/3185459 (if you like short one-liners)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps too.

```
awk '{
match($0,/NM_[^|]*/);
nm=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
match($0,/NP_([^|]|[^$])*/);
np=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
split(np, a,":");
  if(nm && np){
    print $1,nm ":" a[2]
}
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
rs41302905 NM_020469.2:c.802G>A:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745 NM_020469.2:c.771C>T:p.Pro257=
```

**PS:** Since your sample Input_file doesn't have TAB in them so you could add "\t" after awk in case your Input_file is TAB delimited and if you want to have output as TAB delimited too, add OFS="\t" before Input_file.

Answer (score 1):

Short GNU **awk** solution (with `match` function):

```
awk 'match($0,/(NM_[^|]+).*NP_[^:]+([^[:space:]|]+)/,a){ print $1,a[1] a[2] }' input
```

The output:

```
rs41302905 NM_020469.2:c.802G>A:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745 NM_020469.2:c.771C>T:p.Pro257=
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your posted sample input, this is all you need to produce your desired output:

```
$ awk -F'[\t|]+' 'NR>1{sub(/[^:]+/,"",$4); print $1, $3 $4}' file
rs41302905 NM_020469.2:c.802G>A:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745 NM_020469.2:c.771C>T:p.Pro257=
```

If that's not all you need then provide more truly representative input/output.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative awk proposal.

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/\|/," ")sub(/\|NP_065202.2/,"");print $1,$3,$4}' file

rs41302905 NM_020469.2:c.802G>A:p.Gly268Arg
rs8176745 NM_020469.2:c.771C>T:p.Pro257=
```